# Failing Push Notification - Provider Bloc - FormatException

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I have set up Push Notification with Firebase.

A failure is occuring with unclear error message

FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
**strong text**

[image]

I use Bloc

```
class PushNotificationsBloc
    extends Bloc<PushNotificationsEvent, PushNotificationsState> {
  final UserDataRepository userDataRepository;

  PushNotificationsBloc({this.userDataRepository})
      : super(PushNotificationsInitial());

  @override
  Stream<PushNotificationsState> mapEventToState(
    PushNotificationsEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SendNewNotification) {
      yield* mapSendNewNotificationToState(event.map);
    }
  }

  Stream<PushNotificationsState> mapSendNewNotificationToState(Map map) async* {
    yield SendNewNotificationInProgressState();
    try {
      String res = await userDataRepository.sendNewNotification(map);
      if (res != null) {
        yield SendNewNotificationCompletedState(res);
      } else {
        yield SendNewNotificationFailedState();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      yield SendNewNotificationFailedState();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown when you expect A but got B. Then the flutter tries to convert it to object A but it is not possible because you got something else. For example if I expect a JSON that looks like this:

```
{"username": "userName", "password": "password"}
```

I convert this to an object:

```
class User {
  String username;
  String password;
}
```

It works fine. But if something goes wrong and it throws back an exception like:

```
{"Exception": "Internal Server Error"}
```

Then it will show your error because if it tries to convert the exception JSON into a user, it fails.

Comment: I have only issue with Push Notification. the rest of Firebase connection are working fine